# Destructor called two times in C++

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I have a code with two classes like this:

Class A:

```
class A {
    int a, b;
public:
    A(int x, int y) {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "Exit from A\n";
    }
    void values() {
        cout << a << "\n" << b << endl;
    }
};
```

Class B:

```
class B :public A
{
    int c;
public:
    B(int x, int y, int z) :A(x, y)
    {
        c = z;
    }
    ~B() {
        cout << "Exit from B\n";
    }
    void values() {
        A::values();
        cout << c << endl;
    }
};
```

And main function:

```
int main()
{
    A testA(1, 2);
    testA.values();
    B testB(10, 20, 30);
    testB.values();
}
```

That's what i got:

```
1
2
10
20
30
Exit from B
Exit from A
Exit from A
```

First is called destructor from class B, then from A twice. Why two times? I don't know how to change it.

Comment: You have two objects, so of course the destructor is called twice. Once for each object.

Comment: @Devolus but i have 1 object from class A so why two destructors from this class

Comment: *"I don't know how to change it."* - I don't know why you would want to. You have two objects, both of which root from A (one directly, **one by inheritance**), so A *will* be printed once for each of those destructions.

Comment: You have two explicit constructor calls to `A` here. It would be rather weird to have fewer than two `A` destructor calls to match two constructor calls.

Comment: `B` is an `A`, so when you destroy a `B`, you are also destroying an `A`.  That's how inheritance works

Comment: Once the Destructor of A gets called because you have an A object that gets destroyed.
The second call of the A Destructor is because B is a inherited from A so B does actually create and contain an object of A everytime you make an object of B. So when B gets destroyed you have to destroy A as well because an object of A is part of every object of B

Comment: @WhozCraig i would like to have in result: Exit from B and Exit from A just once, can I do that?

Comment: Every `B` *is-a* `A`. If you don't want that behavior, don't make `B` inherit from `A`, as that's slightly the point of inheritance

Comment: `B` inherits from `A`, so part of the process of destructing a `B` is calling a destructor of `A`.   You have an instance of `A` and an instance of `B`, so the destructor of `A` is called twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 `A` objects created in `main`, `testA`, and the `A` base-subobject of `testB`. Both are destroyed at the end of main, in reverse order of how they are declared.

```
class A {
    int a, b;
    std::string msg;
protected:
    A(int x, int y, std::string m) : a(x), b(y), msg(m) {}
public:
    A(int x, int y) : A(x, y, "Exit from A\n") {}
    virtual ~A() {
        std::cout << msg;
    }
    virtual void values() {
        std::cout << a << "\n" << b << std::endl;
    }
};

class B :public A
{
    int c;
public:
    B(int x, int y, int z) : A(x, y, "Exit from B\n"), c(z) {}
    void values() override {
        A::values();
        std::cout << c << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: I understand it now, but is it possible to have in output Exit from A just once?

Comment: You're exiting from `A` twice. If you want to exit from `A` once, then only make one `A`. That's what we're all trying to say. Your output is correctly describing your program. If you want your output to be different, you need a different program for it to correctly describe.

Comment: @keyboardNoob There are many ways to do that. You can move the `cout << "Exit from A\n";` from the destructor to main. You can add a member which will hold the message to `cout` to `A`, and set it to `"Exit from B\n"` in `B`. You can remove the inheritance from `A` in `B`

Answer (score 0):

You have Object `testA` which will call it's destructor from `A` (1).
You have Object `testB` which is derived from `A` so it will call destructor `B` (1) and destructor `A` (2).

This is exactly what your output says.